# Utilidade de referenciamento de Foreign Key (chave estrangeira) no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-primária, chave-estrangeira

Tenho uma dúvida em trabalhos com bancos de dados.

Exemplificando, conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: Relacionamento entre tabelas BD]

Pois bem, eu sei que devo incluir na tabela `agendar_consulta` o usuário que precisa de uma consulta e o médico que irá consultá-lo, e isto se faz através de `foreign keys` referenciando a registros únicos das tabelas `users` e `médicos`.

Agora a pergunta:

**Qual a utilidade de eu referenciar `Foreign Keys` (chaves estrangeiras) da tabela `agendar_consulta` a registros das tabelas `users` e `médicos`?**

Não teria o mesmo efeito eu deixar a tabela `agendar_consulta` com os campos `id_medico` e `id_user` como campos simples (não Foreign Key) de variável Integer e só repetir os id's independentemente das outras tabelas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rodrigo, as chaves estrangeiras são úteis para evitar ações que destroem as ligações entre as tabelas e evita também que dados inválidos sejam inseridos numa chave estrangeira, porque o valor inserido tem de ser um valor existente na tabela que está ligada a essa.

Caso não use as chaves estrangeiras e apenas tenha uma coluna, estas regras não serão aplicadas por omissão.

Usando o seu exemplo, se eu tivesse um `id_user = 1` e depois tentasse inserir na tabela `agendar_consulta` um `user` com `id_user = 2` esta inserção não poderia ser feita, estaria a agendar uma consulta para um `user` não registado, tal como agendar uma consulta com um `id_medico` não existente, não pode realizar uma consulta se o `id_medico` não existir na sua base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Integridade e segurança.

Quando se usa `Foreign Key`, podemos garantir que nenhum registro será fisicamente adicionado na tabela `agendar_consulta` sem um `id_user` e um `id_medico` válido.

O mesmo vale na exclusão: nenhum registro poderá ser excluído das tabelas `users` e `medicos` se estes estiverem sendo usado na tabela `agendar_consulta`